# Is the iOS Keyboard this programmable (for App Store App)?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

Could I make an App which customises the iOS keyboard to contain multi-character buttons like strings and when the user presses those buttons, have a text string outputted?

Also could I use sections to categorise the buttons like the Emojii App does?

Is there limits on how long a Label for a button can be?
And how many sections you can have?

Also, in my App I want those to be user-definable, so the keyboard would dynamically update with what the user programs in my App for button labels, sections and output strings.

This App would have to be App Store approved not Cydia or JB.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `keyboardType` property of a UITextField or UITextView (or other class implementing the UITextInputTraits protocol) to select from a small number of provided keyboards.

Or (since iOS 3.2) you can set a view in the UITextField or UITextView's `inputAccessoryView` property that will automatically be displayed above the keyboard. Or you can set the `inputView` property to completely replace the keyboard with your own view. But note that UITextField provides no way to properly interact with the cursor position, while UITextView doesn't correctly support a single-line display, so this is of very limited utility.

Or you could try some hacks like people use to get a "Done" button on UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad, but Apple may well decide to start rejecting apps that do that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mofify the keyboard. You can only attach a view on top of the keyboard.. like safari do on textfields. ( The Next/Prev Buttons )

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do that. I have to admint I have no clue how, but like the Wolframalpha Courseassistant Algebra does it. You have key like "sin" and "cosin" and "f(x)". So there IS somehow method to do that. Keep on researching!